# Can not match expected type d with actual type b

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

Hello I am new in Haskell and I am having problems.

I want to create a method that is valid for a Partida and for a list of Partidas (Facturas) to do so we have this code:

```
data Bebida a b where {
        Bebida::(Integral a, Fractional b)=>{codigo::a, nombre::[Char], precio::b } -> Bebida a b
    } 

data Partida a b c where {
    ParMult:: (Integral a, Integral c, Fractional b) => {cantidad::c, bebida::Bebida a b} -> Partida a b c;
    ParUnit:: (Integral a, Integral c, Fractional b) => {bebida::Bebida a b} -> Partida a b c
    }

type Factura a b c = [Partida a b c]

class Preciable a where
 precioe :: (Fractional d) => a -> d

instance (Integral a, Fractional b, Integral c) => Preciable (Partida a b c) where
 precioe (ParMult n b) = (fromIntegral(n)*(precio b))
 precioe (ParUnit b) = (precio b)

instance (Integral a, Integral c, Fractional b, Eq b) => Preciable (Factura a b c) where
 precioe f = sum [precioe x | x<-f]
```

I don't know why is giving me this mistake. Can anyone help me telling me why is Haskell giving me this mistake?

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: `precioe :: (Fractional d) => a -> d` promises to work for *any* `d` at all, chosen by the code *calling* `precioe`. Your implementations don't give the caller th at freedom, instead forcing `d` to be the type baked into your `Partida` and `Factura` types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `precioe` is supposed to return any `Fractional` `d` (`Double`, `Rational` etc.). The caller of `precioe` gets to decide what it is.

Your instances of `Preciable` return something that is `Fractional` (`b`), but not necessarily the `Fractional` that the caller of `precioe` wanted (`d`). Fortunately there's a way to create any `Fractional` number `d` using `fromRational :: Fractional d => Rational -> d`

You can turn your `b` to a `Rational` using the `Real` class:

```
class (Num a, Ord a) => Real a where
  toRational :: a -> Rational
```

There's a function that combines these two that also uses rewrite rules for faster conversions between certain types:

```
realToFrac :: (Real a, Fractional b) => a -> b
realToFrac = fromRational . toRational
```

Adding a `Real` constraint to `b` lets your write the instances using `realToFrac`:

```
instance (Integral a, Real b) => Preciable (Partida a b c) where
  precioe (ParMult n b) = fromIntegral n * realToFrac (precio b)
  precioe (ParUnit b)   = realToFrac (precio b)

instance (Integral a, Real b) => Preciable (Factura a b c) where
  precioe f = sum [precioe x | x <- f]
```